# replacing next value with "1"

Tags: r

I have a matrix that contains 1565 rows and 132 columns. All the observations are either "0" or "1". Now I want to keep all the observations same but just one change, i.e whenever there is "1", the very next value in the same row should become "1". Please see below as a sample:

```
>df
 0    0    1    0    0
NA    0    1    1    0
 0    1    0    0    NA
```

What I want is :

```
 0    0    1    1    0
NA    0    1    1    1
 0    1    1    0    NA
```

I shall be thankful for your help.

Saba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to get the row/column index, add 1 to the column index, subset the values and change it to 1.

```
i1 <- which(df==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
i1[,2] <- i1[,2]+1
df[i1] <- 1
df
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    0
#[2,]   NA    0    1    1    1
#[3,]    0    1    1    0   NA
```

If there are NA elements adjacent to 1 and want to keep it as NA, then we can modify the above code with

```
df[i1] <- replace(df[i1], !is.na(df[i1]), 1)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(c(0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, NA), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its really simple to understand and to get accurate results. But I want that if there is NA in the next cell, then this NA should not be replaced by 1. Can I bring some modification in the above code to get required outcome?

Comment: @Saba It is possible, but in your original post that condition was not given.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you so much, It is really helpful.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit vectorisation in matrices just as you do in vectors. Given a matrix `x`, `x[, -1][x[, -ncol(x)] == 1] <- 1` does what you're after. Example and explanation below:

```
# Create sample matrix
set.seed(100)
x <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace = TRUE)
x <- matrix(x, ncol = 10)

# Examine before replacement
x
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    NA
#>  [2,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1    0    1     0
#>  [3,]    1    0    1    1   NA    0   NA    1   NA     1
#>  [4,]    0    1   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA     1
#>  [5,]    1   NA    1   NA    1    1    1    1    0    NA
#>  [6,]    1   NA    0   NA    1    0    1    1    1     1
#>  [7,]   NA    0   NA    0   NA    0    1   NA   NA     1
#>  [8,]    1    1   NA    1   NA    0    1   NA    0     0
#>  [9,]    1    1    1   NA    0    1    0   NA    0     0
#> [10,]    0   NA    0    0    0    0   NA    0   NA    NA

# Replace any cell right-of-1 with 1
x[, -1][x[, -ncol(x)] == 1] <- 1

# Examine after replacement
x
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1     1
#>  [2,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    1    1    1     1
#>  [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0   NA    1    1     1
#>  [4,]    0    1    1   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA     1
#>  [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    NA
#>  [6,]    1    1    0   NA    1    1    1    1    1     1
#>  [7,]   NA    0   NA    0   NA    0    1    1   NA     1
#>  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0     0
#>  [9,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    1   NA    0     0
#> [10,]    0   NA    0    0    0    0   NA    0   NA    NA
```

An explanation of how `x[, -1][x[, -ncol(x)] == 1] <- 1` works:

The logic is to overlay two matrices:

1. `x[, -1]`, which is the original matrix **without the first column**. This is all the data that can be changed. The first column will never be changed because there is nothing to the left.
2. `x[, -ncol(x)]`, which is the original matrix **without the last column**. This is all the data that can signal a change. The last column will never signal a change, because there is nothing to its right.

These two matrices have the same dimensions and, thus, if overlaid, will align cells that can signal a change (matrix 2), with cells that they might change (in matrix 1).

By calling `x[, -1][x[, -ncol(x)] == 1]`, we're asking for all cells in the first matrix (all the potentially changeable cells) wherever there is a cell in the second matrix (all the signalling cells) equal to 1.

`<- 1` finishes this off by assigning these cells the value of 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solves the problem and your explanation has made it understandable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` with some helper functions from `dplyr` package, you can shift the matrix to the right side by `1` and then `or`(`|`) with the original matrix, since `1 | (1,0,NA) = 1`, this converts the value after `1` to `1`; Use `coalesce` function to convert all `NA`s in the shifted matrix to `0` to avoid `0` being converted to `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)
t(apply(mat, 1, function(r) as.integer(r | lag(coalesce(r, 0L), default = 0))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    0
#[2,]   NA    0    1    1    1
#[3,]    0    1    1    0   NA
```

Or you can use base R:

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(r) as.integer(r | c(0, replace(r[-length(r)], 
                                                        is.na(r[-length(r)]), 0)))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    0
#[2,]   NA    0    1    1    1
#[3,]    0    1    1    0   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that prior modifications col-to-col dont count as a positive signal.

```
set.seed(1)
nr    = 1565
nc    = 132
input = matrix(sample(c(0,1),nr*nc,replace=TRUE),nrow = nr,ncol=nc)
makeNext1 = function(){
  out = input
  for(ixCol in c(1:(nc-1))){
    ix = which(input[,ixCol] == 1)
    if(length(ix) > 0)
      out[ix,ixCol + 1] = 1
  }
  out
}
result = makeNext1()
```